# Drag & Drop: How can I make an image go back to it's original position?

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop

Here is a jsFiddle of the general concept of what I have going:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xRXj/1/

HTML & JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

<body>

    <div id="bracelet">

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    </div>

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag1" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag2" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag3" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

            <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag4" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

                <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag5" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

                    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag6" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

                        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag7" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag8" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag9" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

            <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag10" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

                <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag11" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>

                    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img id="drag12" src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 50px
}

#div2 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#bracelet {
    width:420px;
    height:75px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background-color: gray;   
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to move an image onto the drop-spot and then just place it anywhere else and have it return to where it originally was. Currently it can only be dropped on the div's designated, but I would like for it to be able to be dropped anywhere to return to where it originally was.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (unrelated to the question) You should never have two elements in the same document with the same `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine if the element was dropped outside of a droppable element by using the `dragend` event.

```
<img ... draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd(event)" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

```
function dragEnd(ev){
    if(ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect == "none"){

        // REVERT BACK TO ORIGINAL POSITION

    }
}
```

Then you have to decide how you want to designate what the "original position" was.  You might consider storing the `id` of the original parent in a `data-` attribute and then read that and append back to that parent.  The other option could be to populate these `data-` attributes through javascript on initial page load or even on first `dragstart`.

**EDIT:** Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xRXj/3/

You'll notice I had to eliminate your duplicated `id`s as they must be unique.

```
function drag(ev) {
    var el = ev.target;
    var parent = el.getAttribute("data-parent");

    // if the parent data attribute is not yet set, set it to current parent
    if(!parent){
        el.setAttribute("data-parent", el.parentNode.id);
    }

    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", el.id);
}

function dragEnd(ev){
    if(ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect == "none"){

        // get parent from data attribute
        var parent = document.getElementById(ev.target.getAttribute("data-parent"));

        // append back to the original parent            
        parent.appendChild(ev.target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have asked for anything better. Thanks a bunch!